# Create a series of text clip and concatenate them into a video using moviepy

Tags: python, video-processing, moviepy

1. In MoviePy there is an api to create a clip from text as well as to concatenate list of clips.
2. I am trying to create a list of clips in a loop and then trying to concatenate them.
3. Problem is every time it creates a video file of 25 seconds only with the last text in a loop.

Here is the code

```
for text in a list:
    try:
        txt_clip = TextClip(text,fontsize=70,color='white')
        txt_clip = txt_clip.set_duration(2)
        clip_list.append(txt_clip)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        txt_clip = TextClip("Issue with text",fontsize=70,color='white')
        txt_clip = txt_clip.set_duration(2) 
        clip_list.append(txt_clip)
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clip_list)
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4",fps=24, codec='mpeg4')
```

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to recreate your issue (maybe because the list I used doesn't raise the exception?), but the code chunk below works for me. The most significant difference from what you have above is that I set an option for MoviePy to adjust varying frame sizes.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

text_list = ["Piggy", "Kermit", "Gonzo", "Fozzie"]
clip_list = []

for text in text_list:
    try:
        txt_clip = TextClip(text, fontsize = 70, color = 'white').set_duration(2)
        clip_list.append(txt_clip)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        txt_clip = TextClip("Issue with text", fontsize = 70, color = 'white').set_duration(2) 
        clip_list.append(txt_clip)

final_clip = concatenate(clip_list, method = "compose")
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4", fps = 24, codec = 'mpeg4')
```

If you had an example that raises the unicode encode error, maybe I would be able to reproduce your issue. You may find this other question useful: [How to concatenate videos in moviepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758474/how-to-concatenate-videos-in-moviepy)

Comment: I have a similar but slightly different issue with `concatenate`, can you take a look https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/904