# How to concatenate multiple videos using moviepy

Tags: python, mp4, moviepy

Yeah, basically we want to join multiple videos like this:
1 + 1 + ...= 11... (1:video)
sorry that's the best example i could come up with on the spot.
and export them to be one video

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you look at the [user guide](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) of moviepy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate videos in moviepy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758474/how-to-concatenate-videos-in-moviepy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer this Example:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

# Read files
vid1 = VideoFileClip("video1.mp4")
vid2 = VideoFileClip("video2.mp4")
vid3 = VideoFileClip("video3.mp4")

# Concat them
final = concatenate_videoclips([vid1, vid2, vid3])

# Write output to the file
final.write_videofile("newVideo.mp4")
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

A had problems with the solution when tried to concatenate two .avi videos. I used the solution by 'night vision',
to create not .avi, but mp4 instead, using mp4 codec

```
def concatenate_videos(list_videos,newname):
    
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

    concatinated = concatenate_videoclips([VideoFileClip(v) for v in list_videos])

    concatinated.write_videofile(newname + '.mp4', codec='libx264')
```